# Accessing multiple bitmap images in a swc file by using getdefinitionbyname

Tags: actionscript-3, air, swc

I received from my client a **SWC** file with hundreds of png images that all have **AS Linkage** such as *image1_1_1, image1_1_2, image1_2_1, image2_1_3* and so on. I have these same linkage names in an **XML** file that i'm loading. 
All the images are linked with the **BitmapData** class as **base class**.

The problem is that when i try to dynamically create new bitmaps from the xml file and the linkage names by using **getDefinitionByName** i get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable image1_1_1 is not defined.
```

My code for creating the bitmaps is as follows:

```
var BmDataClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(xmlImage) as Class;
var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BmDataClass());
```

where **xmlImage** is the variable in a for each loop, looping through the xml file.

I trace xmlImage so i know it coresponds to the correct name in the SWC file.

Does anyone have any idea why i get this error?
Would appreciate any hints or solutions  :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var imageName:String = "xxx";
var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(imageName) as Class;

var bmp:BitmapData = new myClass(0, 0) as BitmapData;
var img:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to have been as described in the accepted Answer to this thread

[Instantiate a class from a string in ActionScript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934141/instantiate-a-class-from-a-string-in-actionscript-3)

And also slightly explained on this page

http://producerism.com/blog/flashpunk-dame-and-lua-tutorial-part-6/

under the paragraph titled **getDefinitionByName**

Which for me sadly messed up a large part of the project. Ah well... new solutions presents themselves every day  :-)